# c++ static won't link

Tags: c++, static, linkage

Can you help?
The following code:

```
class MT
{
public:
    static int ms_number;

};

int MT::ms_number;
```

yields:

```
Error   8   error LNK2005: "public: static int MT::ms_number" 
      (?ms_number@MT@@2HA) already defined in ProjName.obj
```

Why?

Comment: There's no reason why this question should be tagged community wiki.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to move this line:

```
int MT::ms_number;
```

out of your .h file and into a single .cpp file.

Comment: great! it works! thanks!

but why? what's the problem of it to be in the .h?

Comment: @Hellfrost: You're only allowed to define it once. If it's in a header, then it will end up being defined in every source file that includes the header.

Answer (score -2):

The static needs to be defined as extern, in addition to R Samuel Klatchko's answer.

Comment: No it doesn't. That's only needed for objects at namespace scope, not static class members.